# SQL calculate and sum data based on data by month

Tags: sql, group-by, nested, inner-join, subtotal

I have a huge table with multiple months of product order history.  I want to flatten the table to have columns as date fields with the total amount ordered.  See table below:

[image]

Ideal output would be:

[image]

I've tried case statements

```
Case when ReportMonth = '2021-07-01' then sum(total) end as '2021-07-01',
Case when ReportMonth = '2021-06-01' then sum(total) end as '2021-06-01',
Case when ReportMonth = '2021-05-01' then sum(total) end as '2021-05-01',
Case when ReportMonth = '2020-05-01' then sum(total) end as '2020-05-01',
```

But then I end up with null values and more records.

Comment: Please show fuller SQL for context not line snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reversing the nested expression by running the `CASE` statements inside `SUM`:

```sql
SELECT 
     Parent_Org
    -- , ...other group columns
    , Category
    , SUM(CASE WHEN ReportMonth = '2021-07-01' THEN total END) AS '2021-07-01'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN ReportMonth = '2021-06-01' THEN total END) AS '2021-06-01'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN ReportMonth = '2021-05-01' then total END) AS '2021-05-01'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN ReportMonth = '2020-05-01' THEN total END) AS '2020-05-01'
FROM myTable
GROUP BY
     Parent_Org
    -- , ...other group columns
    , Category
```